# Does it make sense to correlate a rate statistic with the variable that is used to calculate the rate?

Tags: correlation

In this situation, we have a bunch of programs that have slots they can enroll folks into. They range in size from 20 slots to 500.
I am curious if the # of slots is correlated with their slot utilization, which is actual enrollment/slots.
Since slot size is in the denominator of the rate, it seems like there is already an indirect relationship between the two variables. By virtue of how the variable is calculated, if the slot size is bigger, then the rate will be smaller since the denominator is bigger. Or am I just making an elementary math mistake? I want to be sure that a correlation would be a meaningful statistic in this kind of scenario.
Hopefully that makes sense. TIA!

Comment: It rather depends on why slots are the size they are.  Are they based on past demand, or on available resources unrelated to demand, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test: Suppose your assumption is incorrect and each program size $(n_i)$ has the same enrollment rate $p$.  Also, assume each program is independent.  Then the # of enrollments of program $i$, $x_i \sim Bin(n_i,p)$. Suppose there are $m$ programs.  Let $L_{H_0} = \prod_{i=1}^m p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n_i-x_i}$ denote the likelihood under the null hypothesis of identical enrollment rate.  To see if the enrollment rate depends on $n_i$ we could model $p_i$ as a function of $n_i$ through a simple logistic regression model (using a linear term for program size $n_i$).  Specifically, we model the enrollment rate as $p_i = \frac{\exp \left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 n_i \right)}{1+\exp \left(\beta_0 + \beta_1 n_i \right)}$.  Let $L_{H_1} = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{n_i-x_i}$ denote the likelihood under the alternative hypothesis that enrollment rate depends on program size.  Calculate the likelihood ratio statistic.  In this case it will have an asymptotic chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom.  This is equivalent to testing for the inclusion of the $\beta_1$ in the simple logistic regression model.  One can modify the approach by fitting a smooth function of $n_i$ instead of the GLM set-up (see for instance a GAM).

Comment: So the question you are asking is whether the relationship can be modeled as a logistic regression?

Comment: Exactly.  But this is not the only way to develop a test of hypothesis that could be meaningful for you